# How to determine the SPIFFS size on an esp8266-01?

Tags: esp8266

I'm confused about my esp8266-01 if they have SPIFFS or not. Is there a way to find it out? If they have, how to get their size?

I've got the following flash id: `0x1440e0`.

Example SPIFFS apps keep crashing with `wdt reset` and lots of dumped hexes.

Comment: SPIFFS size is determined by **you** when you upload the sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know the size of the flash memory attached to esp8266 on your module. Common sizes are 512 kB (4Mbit), 1 MB (8Mbit) and 4 MB. Espressif [Flash Download Tool](http://espressif.com/en/support/download/other-tools) (Windows) or [esptool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) can determine it.

You can choose the size of the SPIFFS in your [flash 'layout'](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/filesystem.html) by selecting the option in IDE Tools menu. Take one according to for you flash size and size of the files you want to put into SPIFFS.

If you have 1 MB flash on your module and you want to use OTA upload, let flash space for twice a space taken by the sketch.

Comment: All the data like WiFi config and binaries go to the flash memory? There is no other dedicated memory for those?

Comment: no. esp8266 uses the flash memory like a PC uses a hard-drive

Comment: Also, more importantly, I'm getting `wdt reset` errors with sometimes lots of hex dumps after uploading SPIFFS example apps. I've set the SPIFFS size to 512 (of 1M flash), but not sure if the `Flash mode` is correct. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: did you upload the SPIFFS image with the SPIFFS upload IDE plugin?

Comment: I've tried that as well as formatting the SPIFFS using the example code. Not sure what would be a working strategy. I've tried the following among others https://www.pastiebin.com/5ab790f66e9a1

Comment: Please have a look that pastebin code I placed. I'm unable to single upload and then run it without getting `wdt reset` errors. I have erased the esp with esptool prior to uploading it, didn't make any difference.

Comment: try some readonly example first. without formating. upload the spiffs from IDE https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin#arduino-esp8266-filesystem-uploader-

Comment: Tried with a different device and it worked. Both have 1M flash but differ in manufacturer. Does this mean the ESP lib doesn't support one?

Comment: do you use esp8266 core 2.4.1? the issue is known, but I do not know if it is fixed in the release https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4061

Comment: I was using 2.4.1, then I removed it and manually installed the latest via git, so that I could apply both patches (not at the same time) from the link you showed. I might retry it as it was really late yesterday, might have done something wrong. Although some guy had no problem with his 001440E0 device which I am having problem with.

Comment: erase the flash or upload empty SPIFFS before the next test with the patch

Comment: The command with esptool is `esptool flash_id` and its output will contain something like `Detected flash size: 512KB`.